# How to reference the clicked legend item in highcharts?

Tags: javascript, reference, highcharts, legend

I am using Highcharts JS for a project and I can't figure out how to reference the clicked legend item. I want to toggle a class to the legend item clicked so I can add different styles to active/disabled legend items.

When I use the  legedItemClick event I see the console log fired but I can not find children. (probably because this referres to the series and not the legend item). Example:

```
plotOptions:{
    line:{
        marker:{
            symbol:'circle',
            enabled: false
        },
        events: {
            legendItemClick: function () {
                $(this).addClass('new_class');
                console.log('click click');
                $(this).find('.legend-name').toggleClass('visible_true').toggleClass('visible_false');
                $(this).find('.legend-icon').toggleClass('visible_true').toggleClass('visible_false');
            }
        },
        showCheckbox: false
    }
},
```

When I'm trying to not use highcharts click event but use jQuery click handlers on a span inside the legend item instead nothing happens, not even a console log will fire. This probably because of the default click handler of highcharts preventing bubbling or something. Example:

```
$('body').delegate('.highcharts-legend-item span', 'click', function(){

    console.log('click');

    $(this).find('.legend-name').toggleClass('visible_true');
    $(this).find('.legend-icon').toggleClass('visible_true');
});
```

Comment: Found a solution, using $(event.target)

Working example:

    `plotOptions:{
     line:{
      marker:{
       symbol:'circle',
       enabled: false
      },
      events: {
                legendItemClick: function () {
                 $(event.target).parent().find('.legend-name').toggleClass('visible_true').toggleClass('visible_false');
                 $(event.target).parent().find('.legend-icon').toggleClass('visible_true').toggleClass('visible_false');
                }
            },
      showCheckbox: false
     }
    },`

Comment: If you have a solution, please post it as an answer :)